# SSRS 2008 Truncate Textbox Contents

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In Sql Server Reporting 2008, is there a way to truncate the text if it exceeds the bounds of the width of the textbox? Right now it always wraps to the next line, and even though the textbox diallows its height to stretch vertically, the wraparound is still attempted and it is obvious to the report reader/user. I wish the portion of text to the right of the right horizontal boundary of the textbox to not exist.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the CanGrow property to False.  This should force the textbox to remain its original size.